# How to fit a length of drainage PVC pipe between two existent fittings

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I need to connect two lines of 100mm PVC that are about 1,5 meter apart, they are about 50 cm sloped from each other, so I tought about using two 45° elbows. See image below (black: existing fittings, blue: new piping, orange: elbows).

[image]

As far as planning goes it was all fine, but I cannot make the new pipe fit between the ones already in place, they are not "bendy" enough... What is the proper way to do it?

BTW: This is a drainage pipe.

Comment: Is this drainage or pressure pipe?

Comment: Drainage... I will edit the post

Answer (score 2):

For drainage, you can use a mechanical gear type coupling such as a fernco coupling:

[image]

You can slide it over the pipe you're installing, and then once the pipe is in place, slide it back over the joint and tighten the gear clamps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the two pipes are not parallel, so with two 45 bends once one bend is installed, the other won't align with the other pipe; correct? The Fernco flexible coupling suggested may work, but it has a limitation on how many degrees of deflection is allowable. One solution is to put on one 45 bend, then two 90 bends for angle adjustment, then connect the other 45 bend to the second pipe. Without pictures I don't know if this will work, but hopefully you may find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the dates.  Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Necromancers are welcome on the Stack!